# How to extract a value that is always before a specific string

Tags: r

My dataset comes from an OCR routine im running. Sometimes it comes with rows that do not contain the data i need (these rows usually come with no numeric characters)
I'm specifically looking for the **4-digit number** which isn't always on the same column.

```
structure(list(text.V1 = c("NIT", "NIT", "NIT", "NIT", "NIT", 
"ORIGEN", "NIT", "NIT"), text.V2 = c("900914254", "900914254", 
"900914254", "900914254", "900914254", "DE", "900914254", "900914254"
), text.V3 = c("Linea", "Linea", "Linea", "Unea", "Linea", "LA", 
"Linea", "Linea"), text.V4 = c("980001", "980001", "980001", 
"980001", "880001", "GESTION", "980001", "980001"), text.V5 = c("No", 
"No", "No", "No", "No", "Orden", "No", "No"), text.V6 = c("8198", 
"8194", "8193", "8267", "8292", "medica", "8263", "8266"), text.V7 = c("ORIGEN", 
"ORIGEN", "ORIGEN", "ORIGEN", "ORIGEN", "", "ORIGEN", "ORIGEN"
), text.V8 = c("DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "DE", "", "DE", "DE"), 
    text.V9 = c("LA", "LA", "LA", "LA", "LA", "", "LA", "LA"), 
    text.V10 = c("GESTION", "GESTION", "GESTION", "GESTION", 
    "GESTION", "", "GESTION", "GESTION")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

I have this function that looks for the ORIGEN word and then takes the previous column value. This wont work when there are rows with different structure

```
image_1_df_3 = data.frame(X1 = apply(image_1_df_3, 1, function(x) x[grep("ORIGEN", x)-1]))
 
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0
```

EDIT

Comment: based on your data and the code showed, I am not getting any errors.  Can you show the `dput` of the example. Are those `NA` elements as blanks

Comment: i.e. if you have some more conditions with 4 digit number then `apply(image_1_df_3, 1, function(x) {i1 <- grep("ORDEN", x); i2 <- i1 -1 ; x_val <- x[i2]; if(nchar(x[i2]) == 4 && grepl("^\\d{4}$", x[i2])) as.numeric(x[i2]) else NA})#
[1] 8198 8199 8200   NA 8201   NA`

Comment: please see EDIT

Comment: Is the string 'ORIGEN' or 'ORDEN' because in your dput there are no strings with 'ORDEN'

Comment: sorry about that. that was a typo when posting a smaller example here. im aware on that  and its  being considered when testing. error isnt related to that :)
FIXED on edit

Comment: In your data, the 6th row have ORIGEN in first column.  So, if we do a `- 1`, it creates 0 index and R starts from index 1

Comment: ohhh thanks for catching that! is there a way i could get rid of the rows with no numbers then? should that be a possibility?

Comment: It may be better to have NA there or do you want to remove those rows?

Comment: i think remove would be better. can you please advise on some approach for thar removal?

Comment: I posted a solution below.  Hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error shows up when the first column have a value 'ORIGEN' and when we do try to get the value on the previous column with `- 1`, the index becomes 0.  As `R` starts indexing from 1, this creates an imbalance.  Either we can remove that row from being used in `apply`

```
# // check for first column values that are not equal to "ORIGEN"
ind <- image_1_df_3[[1]] != 'ORIGEN'
# // use that as index to subset the rows
apply(image_1_df_3[ind, ], 1, function(x) {
    # // find the index of ORIGEN for each row
    i1 <- grep("ORIGEN", x)
    # // get the previous value index
    i2 <- i1 -1 
    # // subset the row value
    x_val <- x[i2]
    # // create a condition to check whether there are 4 characters
    # // and they are all digits
    # // then return the numeric convert value
    if(nchar(x[i2]) == 4 && grepl("^\\d{4}$", x[i2])) {       
           as.numeric(x[i2]) 
      # // or else return NA
     } else NA
    })
#   1    2    3    4    5    7    8 
#8198 8194 8193 8267 8292 8263 8266
```

Or may have to apply the condition from the second element onwards

Comment: thanks. im struggling with the fact that the word ORIGEN can be in any column. so validating just the first columns wont be sufficient

Comment: @AndresMora But, the issue is only with first column because when you do 1 -1 = 0 and for other columns it is not an issue (if I understand your question)

Answer (score 1):

I have been considering adding two dummy columns to the beginning of the dataframe so the function wont find any index 0 issues

```
  image_1_df_3 = image_1_df_3 %>% add_column(new_col = NA, .after = 0)
  image_1_df_3 = image_1_df_3 %>% add_column(new_col = NA, .after = 0)
  image_1_df_3 = data.frame(X1 = apply(image_1_df_3, 1, function(x) x[grep("ORIGEN", x)-1]))
```